# How to properly read local json file and store the data from it in variables in Android studio?

Tags: java, json, android-studio

I have a `JSON file`, which I've stored in the `assets` folder locally.

[image: Folder hierarchy]

The content of the file has two JSON arrays, `cats` and `services` , stored in a JSON object:

```
{
"result": 0,
"msg": "No error",
"cats": [
        {
            "catid": 1,
            "catnameEN": "Mobile Network Operators"
        },
        {
            "catid": 2,
            "catnameEN": "SIP and Landline"
        },
        {
            "catid": 3,
            "catnameEN": "ISP and VoIP Providers"
        },
        {
            "catid": 23,
            "catnameEN": "Utility Bills"
        },
],  
 "services": [
        {
            "srvid": 98,
            "catid": 1,
            "paymin": ".1000",
            "paymax": "2000.0000",
            "fixedprice": 0,
            "servicenameEN": "Super Mobile",
        },
        {
            "srvid": 90,
            "catid": 1,
            "paymin": ".0500",
            "paymax": "2000.0000",
            "fixedprice": 0,
            "servicenameEN": "International Operator",
        },
        {
            "srvid": 91,
            "catid": 1,
            "paymin": ".5000",
            "paymax": "2000.0000",
            "fixedprice": 0,
            "servicenameEN": "Z-MOBILE",
        },
    {
        "srvid": 296,
        "catid": 2,
        "paymin": ".5000",
        "paymax": "1000.0000",
        "fixedprice": 0,
        "servicenameEN": "Telecom Payphone",
    },
    {
        "srvid": 51,
        "catid": 3,
        "paymin": ".5000",
        "paymax": "1000.0000",
        "fixedprice": 0,
        "servicenameEN": "Fast Internet",
    },
}
```

These two arrays share the same `catid`, the purpose of it is to link two SQL tables with ID. So when a category with `id = 1` is pressed, I will query to return all services that has `id = 1.`

My thought is to store these two arrays (`cats` and `services`) in some type of data structure (Array?) in Java separately and only store `catid`, `catnameEN`, `servicenameEN` data, and then loop through in order to one by one execute SQL insert operation.

How should I read this local file? How should I store the data?

Comment: if file is not big enough (and just one file), you can read that in memory and then use jsonpath ``$.services[?(@.catid==1)] `` or ``$.cats[?(@.catid==1)]`` in order to filter based on catid